# alternative equivalent of mass spring ODE with a dirac delta stimulus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A mass spring system ODE with a dirac delta stimulus reads:

$$mx’’+cx’+kx=\delta(t)$$
$$x(0)=0, x’(0)=0$$

where ’‚’ denotes t derivative.

Textbooks usually say, according to momentum theorem, the ODE can be rewritten as:

$$mx’’+cx’+kx=0, t>0$$
$$x(0+)=0, x’(0+)=\frac 1m$$

However, momentum theorem I think is just one way of treating integration here. In theory, one can always integrate mx’’+cx’+kx=dirac(t) on both sides w.r.t t within (0-,0+). Then momentum theorem chooses to keep the integral of mx’’ dropping the latter 2 integrals. What if instead keep the integral of cx’ dropping the other 2 integrals? Then the ODE will become:

$$mx’’+cx’+kx=0, t>0$$
$$x(0+)=\frac 1 c, x’(0+)=0$$

However, physically this gives a different solution/motion than the original ODE! Where does the error come from?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no choice there. The terms on the left-hand side must add up to the right-hand side. This can be satisfied if $x''$ contains a delta spike, $x'$ contains a step and $x$ contains a kink at $t=0$. If $x$ were to contain a step, $x'$ would contain a delta spike, and $x''$ would contain the derivative of a delta spike, which doesn't appear on the right-hand side, so it can't appear on the left.

Comment: Great answer thanks. What if integrate the ODE on both sides? Then if x has a step, mx’’ and kx after integration vanish, then both sides balance. So seems x having a step is correct in an integral’s sense?

Comment: @feynman: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I don't think anything like that will work. First, one usually wants to satisfy the given equation; I'm not sure what would be gained by satisfying a different one. But even if you integrate it, the problem wouldn't change; you'd just be shifting it by one level. You'd then have a step function on the right, whereas on the left, the integration of the delta derivative in $mx''$ would yield a delta. Integrating an unsatisfied equation again yields an unsatisfied equation. But perhaps I don't understand what you mean; feel free to elaborate.

Comment: $\int{(mx''+cx'+kx)}dt=\int{\delta(t)}dt$

Comment: @feynman: So that gives you $mx'+cx+k\int x\mathrm dt=\Theta$. If $x$ has a step, $x'$ has a delta, but there's no delta to cancel it.

Comment: $m[x'(0+)-x'(0-)]+c[x(0+)-x(0-)]+\int{kx}dt=1$

Comment: if x has a step, $c[x(0+)−x(0−)]=1$, x' is delta but $m[x′(0+)−x′(0−)]=0$ because 0+ has passed the delta spike. ∫kxdt vanishes too within [0-,0+].

Comment: @feynman: Well, now you've basically shown that a delta derivative isn't visible if you integrate it with a constant function. That doesn't mean it's not there. You can't just integrate the equation to be solved in one particular fashion and claim that you've solved it if that integrated version is solved. If you integrate with a test function with non-zero derivative at $t=0$ instead, you'll pick up the delta derivative, and the resulting equation won't be satisfied. ($\int\delta'(t)f(t)\mathrm dt=-\int\delta(t)f'(t)\mathrm dt=-f'(0)$)

Comment: I agree with you! But even if x'' is a delta, then x' is a step and x has a kink, leading to an imbalance of both sides of the original ODE? delta is singular at its center, and only makes sense in an integral sense I guess? @joriki

Comment: @feynman: No. If $x''$ is a delta, $x'$ is a step and $x$ has a kink, things can balance out. It's just that the highest-order discontinuity must be only in $x''$, not in the others. The lower-order discontinutities are also in $x''$. For instance, as you hit the mass with a hammer, you instantaneously impart momentum to it. This is a delta acceleration, which results in a step discontinuity in the velocity. That corresponds to a step discontinuity in the frictional force proportional to the velocity, so there's a step discontinuity in the acceleration, too.

Comment: @feynman: Moreover, the impact results in a kink in the position, which corresponds to a kink in the restoring force of the spring, so there's a kink in the acceleration, too. All this can balance out to to all orders, as long as the highest order is only in $x''$.

Comment: @feynman: I don't know what to do about that – what sort of technical issues?

Comment: The technical issues are out. How to understand "All this can balance out to to all orders, as long as the highest order is only in x′′"? How can delta+step+kink on the LHS of the ODE balance out the delta on the RHS

Comment: @feynman: I explained above that the step occurs in both $x''$ and $x'$ and the kink occurs in both $x''$ and $x$, so they balance on the left-hand side, without a step or a kink on the right-hand side. This is a too extended discussion in the comments. If you have further questions, please ask them as a new question.